# Boolean Algebras admit Separative Partial Orders

Tags: set-theory

In Chapter 14 of Jech's *Set Theory*, he writes that if $B$ is a Boolean algebra, then $(B^+,<)$ is a separative partial order. I'm having trouble seeing why this is the case.

For the definition of a Boolean algebra and the corresponding order:
[image]

Given a Boolean Algebra $B$, $B^+$ is given by $B\setminus \{0\}$.

A partial order is *separative* if for all $p,q$: if $p\not\leq q$ then there exists some $r\leq p$ that is incompatible with $q$; that is, for all $s$ it is not the case that both $s\leq r$ and $s\leq q$.

With the definitions established, I have a few questions:

1. Jech claims it is easy to see that the ordering on $B$ is a partial order. I'm having some trouble seeing why this is the case. Showing that $u\leq u$ and $(u\leq v \wedge v\leq w)\to(u\leq w)$ are not particularly hard, but I'm having trouble seeing why $(u\leq v\wedge v\leq u\to u=v)$. I'm sure there's a simple argument but I'm not finding it.
2. I'm not quite sure why this partial order is separative once you exclude $0$. First, is my understanding of what it means for a partial order to be separative correct? If so, I saw [Asaf Karagila's answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539230/is-every-boolean-algebra-a-separative-partial-order), but I don't understand how the calculations there yield that for all $z\leq x$, $z\perp y$; it seems like it only shows a specific one. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Your definition of "separative" is correct. Note that is says "there exists $r$" (not "for all $r$"). So I don't see your problem with Asaf's answer that you linked to. He gets a single $z$, but that's all he needs.

Comment: Ah, I was mixing up the $\exists z$ in the first line with the $\lnot\exists z$ in the second. That being said, I still don't understand why $z\cdot y=0$ implies $z\perp y$. Do you know why that holds?

Comment: Usually, the disjointness relation, $z\bot y$, is defined to mean $z\cdot y=0$.

Comment: @ConnorGordon You should demonstrate that for all $x, y, z$, we have $x \leq y$ and $x \leq z$ iff $x \leq z \cdot y$. Therefore, if $z \cdot y = 0$, there can be no $x \in B^+$ such that $x \leq z$ and $x \leq y$, since in this case, we would have $x \leq z \cdot y = 0$ and therefore $x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p,q\in B$ \ $\{0\}$ with $p\not\le q.$ Let $r=p(-q).$ Then $r\ne 0$ because $r=0\implies p=p(1)=p( (-q)+q)=p(-q)+pq=0+pq=pq\implies p\le q.$

Now if $s\in B$ \ $\{0\}$ then  $(s\le r\land s\le q)\implies s=sr=sq\implies$ $\implies s=ss=(sr)(sq)=(ss)(rq)=(ss)(p(-q)q)=(ss)(p\cdot 0)=0,$ a contradiction to $s\in B$ \ $\{0\}.$

BTW some authors (e.g. Kunen) use a slightly different definition of s separative poset $P$, that is, $\forall x\in P\,\exists y,z\in P\,(y\le x\land z\le x\land y\perp z).$ If $B=\{0,1\}$ is a Boolean alegebra and $P=\{1\}$ then according to Kunen's definition, $P$ is not separative.